# SAS: Assign a macro

Tags: macros, sas

How to assign a variable that contains a string to a macro? 
I've put my question in the comments of code below:

```
%let HOLD_MONTHS=1; 

data _null_;
if &HOLD_MONTHS=1 then hold='h1m';
*temp='model_h1m';
temp=catx('_','model',hold);
*how to assign 'model_h1m to the macro a?;
%let a = %str(temp );
run;
*now the following print "temp";
%put &a;
```

Comment: The `%let` statement is executed at macro-compile-time, i.e. even before the data step is compiled. At that moment, `temp` only exists qs a text, part of the program. There is no such thing as a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `call symput` to assign the value of a variable in a data step, e.g.:

```
%let HOLD_MONTHS=1; 

data _null_;
if &HOLD_MONTHS=1 then hold='h1m';
temp=catx('_','model',hold);
call symput('a',temp);
run;

%put &a;
```

Comment: `call symput` is executed as part of the data step, when ´temp´ is indeed a variable that can contain a value..

Comment: Unlike for instance C++, SAS code is compiled stepwise, so the data step is executed before the `%put &a;`  after the `run` is interpreted. Tha is why SAS has a `call symput` and C++ has no such thing